# Do individual deities restrict inquisitions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

When building an Inquisitor and taking an Inquisition instead of a Domain, are there any restrictions imposed by deities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer will be short, but: **None**.
All [Inquisitions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/inquisitions) are available to all inquisitors.

> While inquisitors often take on the domains permitted to the clerics of the faith, they are privy to special lore not open to priests and other agents of their religion.

All you have is a table of [Suggested Inquisitions according to a Deity Portfolio](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/inquisitions)

Comment: Great, I didn't see any mention of restrictions, but it felt a little weird to me. I'll wait a day to make sure no one else contradicts you, then accept this.